# MySql view is displaying partial column data

Tags: mysql, view

for a Wordpress/Woocommerce webshop I created a pivot view displaying al the orders like:

```
CREATE VIEW vwOrderPivot AS
SELECT  
    PM.post_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_billing_first_name',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS FirstName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_billing_last_name',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS LastName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_billing_address_1',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS Address,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_billing_postcode',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS Postcode,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_billing_phone',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS Phone,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_order_total',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS OrderTotal,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_pickup_location',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS PickupLocation,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_pickup_time',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS PickupTime,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(PM.meta_key = '_order_items',PM.meta_value,NULL)) AS OrderItems
FROM    goe_postmeta AS PM
GROUP BY PM.post_id
```

There is only a slight problem. The data in de OrderItems (a serialized field) contains only half the data from the Original field. Is there some kind of way to solve this? I have no clue. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of
>   group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an
>   unsigned integer:
>
> ```
> SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
> ```

So here you are a workaround, though the best definitive solution would be to rewrite the query and group rows when reading from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) tell you, that the size of `GROUP_CONCAT()` output is limited to the length of the `group_concat_max_len` system variable. This has bitten me more than once.